# asymptotic expansion for integral when integrand is function of limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, singularity-theory

I have the following integral:
$$f(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \dfrac{t^{-\alpha}}{(x - t)^{\frac{3}{2}} } \exp{\left( \dfrac{-A^2 {t}^2}{(x - t)} \right)} dt, A > 0, \alpha > 0$$

I want to calculate the log-log slope of $f(x)$ for $x$ large, say $10^4$. 
I can see numerically (after numerical integration and plotting) that for certain range of values of $A$ and $\alpha$, the log-log slope (abs value) of  $f(x)$ seems to scale as $1 + \alpha/2$, other times like $1 + \alpha$.

I would like to see if asymptotics can get me anywhere towards that, but  this integral seems to not fit any of the standard forms like Laplace. Any ideas ?

Comment: For large $x$ you are essentially averaging a function of a high variance Gaussian, except when $t$ gets close to $x$ (which I think negligibly contributes to the integration anyway). is there any way to change variables to make it a low variance Gaussian instead?

Comment: $f(x)\approx \frac{1}{x^{3/2} (-1+\alpha )}+\frac{-9+4 A^2+3 \alpha -2 A^2 \alpha }{2 x^{5/2} (-3+\alpha ) (-2+\alpha )}$ for: $A>>2$,$\alpha>>2$ and $x  >> 1000$.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Could you write that out in more detail in an answer ?

Comment: I used  **Mathematica 11.3**. Execute this code: `n = 3;(*n Terms*)AsymptoticIntegrate[
 t^-α/(x - t)^(3/2)*Exp[-A^2*t^2/(x - t)], {t, 1, 
  Infinity}, {x, Infinity, n}, Assumptions -> {α > 0, A > 0}]`

Comment: Your integral can be approximated as a sum over confluent hypergeometric functions in the case I examined: $0<\alpha<1$ and large $A\,x.$  Section 13.8 of DLMF shows how there is a transition region as the parameters sweep below to much higher than a large argument.  It would probably be helpful to narrow the scope of your problem.  If you are O.K. with special functions as an answer, I can type it up over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $A$ and $\alpha$, the asymptotic can be found in a way similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2770817); after the change of variables $\xi = t/(x - t)$, the leading term is determined by the maximum of the exponent at $\xi = 0$ but the integration range is $[1/(x-1), \infty)$:
$$f(x) = \int_{1/(x - 1)}^\infty
 \frac 1 {\sqrt {x (\xi + 1)}}
  \left( \frac {x \xi} {\xi + 1} \right)^{-\alpha}
  e^{-A^2 x \xi^2 / (\xi + 1)} d\xi \sim \\
x^{-\alpha - 1/2} \int_{1/(x - 1)}^\infty
 \xi^{-\alpha} e^{-A^2 x \xi^2} d\xi = \\
\frac 1 2 A^{\alpha - 1} x^{-\alpha/2 - 1}
 \Gamma \!\left( \frac {1 - \alpha} 2, \frac {A^2 x} {(x - 1)^2} \right) \sim \\
\frac 1 2 A^{\alpha - 1} x^{-\alpha/2 - 1}
 \Gamma \!\left( \frac {1 - \alpha} 2, \frac {A^2} x \right) \sim \\
\cases {
 \frac 1 2 A^{\alpha - 1} \Gamma \!\left( \frac {1 - \alpha} 2 \right)
  x^{-\alpha/2 - 1} & $\alpha < 1$ \\
  \frac 1 2 x^{-3/2} \ln x & $\alpha = 1$ \\
 \frac 1 {\alpha - 1} x^{-3/2} & $\alpha > 1$ \\},
\quad x \to \infty.$$

Comment: Could you explain the second step a bit more, about why the $\xi + 1$ term has been dropped from the integrand ?

Comment: Also, I understand the derivation of the last part when  $\alpha <1$ but It is not clear to me how you get the expressions when $\alpha \geq 1$.

Comment: We're expanding the exponential and non-exponential parts around $\xi = 0$:
$$\int_{1/(x - 1)}^\infty \phi(\xi) \xi^{-\alpha} e^{x f(\xi)} d \xi \sim
\phi(0) e^{f(0) x} \int_{1/(x - 1)}^\infty \xi^{-\alpha} e^{f''(0) x \xi^2/2} d \xi.$$
For $a \leq 0$, the expansion of $\Gamma(a, z)$ around $z = 0$ is determined by the behavior of the integrand at $\xi = 0$:
$$\int_z^\infty \xi^{a - 1} e^{-\xi} d \xi \sim
\int_z^1 \xi^{a - 1} d \xi.$$

Comment: The expansion of $\phi$ and $f$ around zero---what is the name of this technique ? Is this the Laplace method ? I have been trying to get the general method from a book but not able to yet.

Comment: The expansion is taken around zero only because the maximum of the exponent is at zero. For $\alpha < 1$, the integration range can be extended to $[0, \infty)$, then it's a standard case for Laplace's method (an extension of it to integrable singularities). The case $\alpha > 1$ can be done without Laplace's method as it's the exponential factor that can be replaced by a constant. $\alpha = 1$ is slightly more difficult. Bender, Orszag, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers* has plenty of examples. Another good book is Erdelyi's *Asymptotic expansions*.